# Automate tasks to access data within excel files

Tags: excel, powerquery, vba

I am between beginner and intermediate user of excel with no coding background.  Not sure if I need to use power query or not for this.  If not, any VBA code to accomplish the same would be great.

I want to automate the consolidation of data and processing it for 10 production lines.

Each production line has its own folder on the drive.

Within each line's folder, there is a monthly folder example - March, April etc.

Within each Monthly folder there is a day folder - May 1, May 2 , May 3, etc.

Within each day there are 3 excel files - Shift 1, Shift 2 and Shift 3.

Data for each shift for 10 different lines is collected and manually entered into its specific shift excel file by production operators.

There is a master file located elsewhere on the drive which processes data from these lines but currently it has to be manually transferred to the master file - which is a pain and super time consuming.

The master file contains 2 worksheets for each production line. I would like to copy and paste specific range of cells  (H9:R24) from the shift production line files into specific worksheets within the master file specifically made for those production lines.

The column before the cell ranges where I would like to paste the data (in the master file) contains dates and hence I am hoping that the code/query will help me paste via matching the date from within the shift excel file.

Each shift excel file is exactly the same in terms of naming of columns, formatting, formulas etc.

Once pasted into the specific worksheet within the master file, cells in another worksheet  (within the master file) use these numbers to process these via formulas and more numbers are generated such as waste % etc. which will be automatically plotted on different graphs.

I would like to super automate this process with a click of the button in the master file to access the data within those files, copy and paste into specific cells in specific worksheets within the master file and process data according to specified formula (already within the cell) to ultimately give processed numbers and graphs for each line for the previous day.

This needs to be repeated for 30 files - 3 files each for each day for 10 lines - every single day first thing in the morning.

Not sure if I need to use power query or not for this. If not, any VBA code to accomplish the same would be great.

Requesting you kindest help.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Power Query is the best tool for this task.  You should not need any VBA.

Start with Get Data / From Folder and point it at your root folder for all production lines.  It will browse all the subfolders and give you a list of files, with the path for each, as a table.

As long as the individual file content is consistent, you can then hit Combine to generate a Function Query that will repeat for each file.  You'll need to build your transformation logic in that query.

You can build queries by "Reference" to this main query, e.g. transforming the data for a specific chart requirement.

The "click of a button" will be on Excel's standard Refresh button - that will re-run all the queries and refresh their output tables.  That can be automated with a one-line VBA macro or using the Power Update add-on.

Comment: Hi Mike, 

Is there a way I can attach an image to this message to show you the folder structure ?

Comment: You probably need more reputation.  It doesnt really matter - PQ From Folder will scan every subfolder. The folder path will be returned as a column.